# Tracing a Python gRPC server deployed on Cloud Run with OpenTelemetry

Tags: python, grpc, google-cloud-run, open-telemetry

I'm running a Python gRPC server on Cloud Run and attempting to add instrumentation to capture trace information. I have a basic setup currently, however I'm having trouble making use of propagation as shown in the OpenTelemetry [docs](https://google-cloud-opentelemetry.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/cloud_trace_propagator/README.html).

Inbound requests have the `x-cloud-trace-context` header, and I can log the header value in the gRPC method I've been working with, however the traces created by the OpenTelemetry library always have a different ID than the trace ID from the request header.

This is the simple `tracing.py` module I've created to provide configuration and access to the current `Tracer` instance:

```py
"""Utility functions for tracing."""

import opentelemetry.exporter.cloud_trace as cloud_trace
import opentelemetry.propagate as propagate
import opentelemetry.propagators.cloud_trace_propagator as cloud_trace_propagator
import opentelemetry.trace as trace
from opentelemetry.sdk import trace as sdk_trace
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import export

import app_instance


def get_tracer() -> trace.Tracer:
    """Function that provides an object for tracing.

    Returns:
        trace.Tracer instance.
    """
    return trace.get_tracer(__name__)


def configure_tracing() -> None:
    trace.set_tracer_provider(sdk_trace.TracerProvider())
    if app_instance.IS_LOCAL:
        print("Configuring local tracing.")
        span_exporter: export.SpanExporter = export.ConsoleSpanExporter()
    else:
        print(f"Configuring cloud tracing in environment {app_instance.ENVIRONMENT}.")
        span_exporter = cloud_trace.CloudTraceSpanExporter()
        propagate.set_global_textmap(cloud_trace_propagator.CloudTraceFormatPropagator())

    trace.get_tracer_provider().add_span_processor(export.SimpleSpanProcessor(span_exporter))
```

This `configure_tracing` function is called by the entrypoint script run on container start, so it executes before any requests are handled. When running in Google Cloud, the `CloudTraceFormatPropagator` should be what's required to ensure trace propagation, however it doesn't seem to be working for me.

This is the simple gRPC method I've been implementing with:

```py
import grpc
from opentelemetry import trace
import stripe

from common import cloud_logging, datastore_utils, proto_helpers, tracing
from services.payment_service import payment_service_pb2
from third_party import stripe_client

def GetStripeInvoice(
    self, request: payment_service_pb2.GetStripeInvoiceRequest, context: grpc.ServicerContext
) -> payment_service_pb2.StripeInvoiceResponse:

    tracer: trace.Tracer = tracing.get_tracer()

    with tracer.start_as_current_span('GetStripeInvoice'):
        print(f"trace ID from header: {dict(context.invocation_metadata()).get('x-cloud-trace-context')}")
        cloud_logging.info(f"Getting Stripe invoice.")
        order = datastore_utils.get_pb_with_pb_key(request.order)

        try:
            invoice: stripe.Invoice = stripe_client.get_invoice(
                invoice_id=order.stripe_invoice_id
            )
            cloud_logging.info(f"Retrieved Stripe invoice. Amount due: {invoice['amount_due']}")
        except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
            cloud_logging.error(
                f"Failed to retrieve invoice: {e}"
            )
            context.abort(code=grpc.StatusCode.INTERNAL, details=str(e))

        return payment_service_pb2.StripeInvoiceResponse(
            invoice=proto_helpers.create_struct(invoice)
        )
```

I've even gone as far as adding the `x-cloud-trace-context` header to local client requests, to no avail - the included value isn't used when starting traces.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here - I can see traces in the Cloud Trace dashboard so I believe the basic instrumentation is correct, however there's obviously something going on with the configuration/usage of the `CloudTraceFormatPropagator`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that my configuration wasn't correct - or, I should say, it wasn't complete. I'd followed [this basic example](https://google-cloud-opentelemetry.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/cloud_trace_propagator/README.html) from the docs for the Google Cloud OpenTelemetry library, but I didn't realize that manually instrumenting wasn't needed.

I removed the call to `tracer.start_as_current_span` in my gRPC method, installed the gRPC instrumentation package (`opentelemetry-instrumentation-grpc`), and added it to the tracing configuration step during startup of my gRPC server, which now looks something like this:

```
from opentelemetry.instrumentation import grpc as grpc_instrumentation
from common import tracing # from my original question

def main():
    """Starts up GRPC server."""

    # Set up tracing
    tracing.configure_tracing()
    grpc_instrumentation.GrpcInstrumentorServer().instrument()

    # Set up the gRPC server
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100))
    # set up services & start
```

This approach has solved the issue described in my question - my log messages are now threaded in the expected manner

As someone new to telemetry & instrumentation, I didn't realize that I'd need to take an extra step since I'm tracing gRPC requests, but it makes sense now.

I ended up finding some helpful examples in a [different set of docs](https://opentelemetry-python-contrib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/instrumentation/grpc/grpc.html) - I'm not sure why these are separate from the docs linked earlier in this answer.

EDIT: Ah, I believe the gRPC instrumentation, and thus the related docs, are part of a separate but related project wherein contributors can add packages that instrument libraries of interest (i.e. gRPC, redis, etc). It'd be helpful if it was unified, which is the topic of [this issue](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/issues/2166) in the main OpenTelemetry Python repo.

Answer (score 1):

While reviewing Google Documentation of OpenTelemetry using Python, I found some configurations that could help with the issue of tracing the correct ID. Additionally, there is a troubleshooting document to view traces in your `Google Cloud Project` when you expect trace data to be present.

Python-OpenTelemetry - https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/python-ot

Google Cloud Trace Troubleshooting - https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/troubleshooting

For secure channels, you need to pass in `chanel_type=’secure’`. It is explained in the following link: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python-contrib/issues/365

You need to use the `x-cloud-trace-context` header to ensure your traces use the same trace ID as the load balancer and AppServer on Google Cloud Run, and all link up in Google Trace.

The code below works to see you logs alongside traces in `Google Trace’s Trace List` view:

```
from opentelemetry import trace 
from opentelemetry.trace.span import get_hexadecimal_trace_id, get_hexadecimal_span_id 
       current_span = trace.get_current_span() 
       if current_span: 
          trace_id = current_span.get_span_context().trace_id 
          span_id = current_span.get_span_context().span_id 
          if trace_id and span_id: 
              logging_fields['logging.googleapis.com/trace'] = f"projects/{self.gce_project}/traces/{get_hexadecimal_trace_id(trace_id)}"
              logging_fields['logging.googleapis.com/spanId'] = f"{get_hexadecimal_span_id(span_id)}" 
              logging_fields['logging.googleapis.com/trace_sampled'] = True
```

The documentation and code above were tested using `Flask Framework`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've been referring to the docs you linked, as well as that helpful Github issue. Also, I've confirmed that the `x-cloud-trace-context` header is included in requests to my gRPC server - the issue I'm experiencing is that the tracing library doesn't seem to be discovering that header when attempting to extract it during trace propagation. Does that snippet you pasted work in Flask? I ask because the latest version of `opentelemetry.trace.span` has updated names for the trace and span ID format functions.