# Open-Telemetry spans not showing up in GCP Cloud Trace

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-run, open-telemetry, google-cloud-trace

I am instrumenting a node.js service in Google Cloud Platform's Cloud Run.

I'm running into a problem where **custom spans are not showing up in Trace**.

I know that tracing is working because HTTP/TCP spans (which you get for free in GCP) are showing up nested properly--they wouldn't be nested automatically without configuration, which suggests to me the configuration below is working:

`tracing.ts`:

```js
import { NodeTracerProvider } from "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node";
import {
  SimpleSpanProcessor,
} from "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base";
import { TraceExporter } from "@google-cloud/opentelemetry-cloud-trace-exporter";
import { getNodeAutoInstrumentations } from "@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node";
import { registerInstrumentations } from "@opentelemetry/instrumentation";
import { ExpressInstrumentation } from "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-express";
import * as opentelemetry from "@opentelemetry/api";
import { AsyncHooksContextManager } from "@opentelemetry/context-async-hooks";
import { SemanticResourceAttributes } from "@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions";
import { Resource } from "@opentelemetry/resources"

export const provider = new NodeTracerProvider({
  resource: new Resource({
    [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: "my-service-name",
  })
});

// this *should* work automatically in GCP??
provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(new TraceExporter({
  resourceFilter: /^service\./
})));

provider.register();

opentelemetry.trace.setGlobalTracerProvider(provider);

const contextManager = new AsyncHooksContextManager();
contextManager.enable();
opentelemetry.context.setGlobalContextManager(contextManager);

export const tracer = opentelemetry.trace.getTracer("basic");

// this works (spans are correctly associated with parents)
registerInstrumentations({
  instrumentations: [
    getNodeAutoInstrumentations({
      "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-http": {},
      "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-express": {},
    }),
  ],
});
```

The spans that are **not** showing up are those that are emitted in code like the following redacted production code:

```js
import { tracer } from "../tracing";

// ...

export const doWork = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response
) => {

  // ... but this does *NOT* work: these spans appear nowhere
  // start span
  const span = tracer.startSpan("doWork");
  const ctx = opentelemetry.trace.setSpan(opentelemetry.context.active(), span);
  opentelemetry.propagation.extract(ctx, req.headers);

  try {
    // ... do work here with ctx to emit child spans

    res.status(200).send("ok");
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send("error");
  }

  span.end();
};
```

It is unclear to me why these spans are not showing up anywhere.

The service account that deploys the Cloud Run instance has the `roles/cloudtrace.agent` role:

```
- members:
  - serviceAccount:<my service account name>@<project id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/cloudtrace.agent
```

I am unsure if there are additional permissions that need to be added (or what entity they may need to be added to).

So far I have tried

- deploying with and without Provider configuration (no difference)
- using the Open-Telemetry `OTLPTraceExporter` to export spans in GCP (still nothing shows up)
- using the Stackdriver `trace-agent` instead (not compatible with webpack)
- running all of this locally using the `OTLPTraceExporter` with a Open-Telemetry collector (everything works exactly as expected -- traces all showing up)
- using the ConsoleSpanExporter in GCP (spans show up correctly in logs)

I'm really at a loss.

Comment: based on documentation by GCP, there is [auto-instrumentation](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/nodejs-ot#auto-instrumentation_for_web_applications) module for Google Compute Engine and GKE, but no for Cloud Run. You can check this Github [Cloud Run Support](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/opentelemetry-operations-js/issues/62).

Comment: ah, thanks for the link! I've tried the recommended changes in the linked comment:
 "@patryk-smc I don't have an actual example but tracing should work fine. Use a regular BatchSpanProcessor and call TracerProvider.shutdown() before your program ends. For Cloud Run, you can add a SIGTERM handler to call shutdown." ... but it seems that it just does not work in Cloud Run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As checked in GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/nodejs-ot#auto-instrumentation_for_web_applications), only Google Compute Engine and GKE are supported by this service.

However, you can refer to [Cloud Run Support](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/opentelemetry-operations-js/issues/62) in Github, if you are running OpenTelemetry on Cloud Run and a Stackoverflow [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66357827/trace-propagation-on-google-cloud-run-with-opentelemetry).

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was a combination of a few things:

Using a `BatchSpanProcessor` did the trick for me, even without properly calling `shutdown`.

ie, something like this:

```
 provider.addSpanProcessor(new BatchSpanProcessor(new TraceExporter()));
```

However, not all spans will be sampled on GCP, so I needed to add an `AlwaysOnSampler` in the `NodeTracerProvider`:

```
export const provider = new NodeTracerProvider({
  sampler: new AlwaysOnSampler(), //https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/issues/3057
  resource: new Resource({
    [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: processName,
  }),
});
```

I'm currently not sure why all traces are sampled when running locally, but only a subset are sampled when running on GCP.